# Error al usar Entity Framework Core 3 desde aplicación WinForm .NET en producción

Tags: c#, sql-server, windows-forms, .net, entity-framework-core

Hice un programa con visual studio 2019 con Entity Framework Core, en desarrollo la aplicación funciona perfectamente con la base de datos, el problema esta cuando genero el instalador (cuando lo publico para usarlo desde mi escritorio). Al momento de ejecutarlo desde su acceso directo me salta una excepción:

> Referencia no establecida como instancia de un objeto

.
Lo fui depurando y el problema esta al usar el contexto de Entity Framework (el "Hola 2" nunca se llega a ejecutar):

```
InitializeComponent();
        MessageBox.Show("Hola");
        using (Contexto db = new Contexto())
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Hola 1");
            List<Productos> productosConPendientes = db.productos.Where(x => ((x.cantPendientes > 0) || (x.stock < x.cantMinima))).Include(x => x.proveedor).ToList();
            MessageBox.Show("Hola 2");
        }
```

Mi conexion a SQL es el siguiente:

```
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            if (!optionsBuilder.IsConfigured)
            {

                optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("Server=localhost\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=Meta;User ID=sa;Password = Admin");
            }
        }
```

Agrego el mensaje de error que me tira:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No entiendo porque no funciona si lo estoy probando en la misma pc donde lo desarrollé.

Comment: Para que puedas ver cual es la causa del error, ejecuta la instrucción `List<Productos> productosConPendientes = db.productos.Where(x => ((x.cantPendientes > 0) || (x.stock < x.cantMinima))).Include(x => x.proveedor).ToList();` dentro de un `try-catch`, y dentro del catch guarda o muestra en pantalla la exception que se produce. Con esto podrás saber cual es el error y agregarlo a la pregunta de ser necesario.

Comment: Ahí lo agregué. Probé lo del siguiente link y sigue con el mismo error: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40262151/entity-framework-connection-string-in-app-config  Hace falta si o si un conexion string en App.config? En desarrollo tenía solo en la clase Contexto de Entity y funcionaba bien.

Comment: Intenta instalando está referencia NUGET manualmente Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SNI versión 1.1.1.

Comment: Lo instalé y sigue igual.